# android phonegap and menu crashes with webview

Tags: android, cordova, menu, webview

I'm facing a weird problem with my app:

When pushing the menu button, my app crashes. BUT! only when i launch the app in webview!

**this works :**

```
super.loadUrl("http://www.url.com");
```

menu loads here and all is fine, but since i can't get "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" to work using super.loadurl, i'm trying to launch the app straight into webview.

`mwebview.loadurl("http://url.com");` 
**does work**, but if i push the menu button, it will crash.

my menu is made programmatically like so :

```
 @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Menu that appears when menu button is pressed on device
         Menu m_menu = menu;
         m_menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+6, 0, "Hjem");
         m_menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+7, 0, "Om");
         m_menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+5, 0, "Avslutt");
         return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

Heres my activity:

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        super.setBooleanProperty("loadInWebView", true); 
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.requestFocusFromTouch();
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
            super.setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            super.loadUrl("http://www.url.com/app/index");
//mWebView.loadurl("url");
            }
        private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
             @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Heres the error in catlog :

```
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at com.phonegap.DroidGap.postMessage(DroidGap.java:943)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at com.phonegap.DroidGap.onCreateOptionsMenu(DroidGap.java:1374)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at blogreel.app.HelloAppActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(HelloAppActivity.java:44)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2148)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:305)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDownPanel(PhoneWindow.java:550)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDown(PhoneWindow.java:1192)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1648)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-03 10:00:26.893: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So im asking : 
Any way to make my menu work when loading straight into webview?
Or to make "Shouldoverrideurl" work on all urls when using "super.loadurl"

**edit** 
Have to add that the first page super.loadurl loads does work. the specified url has links that, when clicked, redirects within the same webview. however, the second page's links will trigger in a new browser.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I have managed to add menu button support to PhoneGap and regular Android Webview projects

```
//basic menu button support
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.add("Refresh");
    item = menu.add("Quit");
    return true;
}

//handle menu item selection
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if (item.hasSubMenu() == false)
    {
        if("Quit"==item.getTitle()) {
            finish();
        }
        if("Refresh"==item.getTitle()) {
           super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying :)
And with this method youve used mWebView.loadurl instead of super.loadurl? your approach crashes on my project, but ill keep trying =) it tells me the menuitem item = menu.add line is never read. hmpf!

Comment: No, I use *super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");*

I have updated my example

Comment: Also note you do *super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);* at the end of your method when you are returning

Comment: Changed to return true;
I guess i have to use super.loadurl to pull this off. It's just that the links after the first pageload opens in a new browser. the first window it opens stays in the same webview, which is unwanted, thats why i am trying to use mwebview.loadurl ( which ofc crashes on menuclick).

Comment: works fine.. but m getting msg "The local variable item is never read"